# Why won't maps.google.com autocomplete when other URLs will?

Tags: safari

When I type into the Safari address bar:

- m
- ma
- map
- maps
- maps.
- maps.g
- maps.go
- maps.goo
- maps.goog
- maps.googl
- maps.google
- maps.google.
- maps.google.c
- maps.google.co

at no point does it autosuggest the obvious result I want maps.google.com, which visit several times per day.

In contrast, if I search maps.yahoo.com or maps.bing.com and maps.yandex.ru, websites that I never visited before, they all show the full URL.

I have DuckDuckGo as my search provider.

Comment: Odd. idk why. Mine goes there at just 'm' I use it so often.

Comment: Not sure, but the URL is google.com/maps not maps.google.com

Comment: @Ezekiel - it is once it 'arrives', but not as it 'sets off' - here it is after just typing 'm' https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv7Mr.png

Comment: Well yes, but my point is that (as Mr. Ming pointed out), maps.google.com redirects to google.com/maps with a 302 MOVED which would logically remove it from suggestion lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I access [maps.google.com](https://maps.google.com/), it redirects to [www.google.com/maps](https://www.google.com/maps), maybe that is the reason.

However, you can:

1. Add [www.google.com/maps](https://www.google.com/maps) to your bookmarks (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
2. Open your bookmarks (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) and find **Google Maps** - `https://www.google.com/maps`
3. Select **Edit Address...** from the context menu, and set the address to `https://maps.google.com/`

Then, open a new tab and type `maps`, and the `maps.google.com` should appear.

Comment: Cool, thank you. This makes it autocomplete for me after `maps.g`. Also deleted some of my browser history and got it to work for `map`. Safari will learn, since this is a top site I visit.